# Questions regarding BlackBerry BrowserField2

Tags: java, browser, blackberry, field

does anyone know how to specify the height of a net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField? I cannot find how to do so in the BlackBerry API.

Also, when I use a browser field within my application, am I able to load one page, and from that page click a link and go to another? I am having issues doing that with the BrowserField2...If not, how can I achieve new page loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own manager and override [sublayout](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#sublayout%28int,%20int%29)

After that you can create your own browser field and inherit your manager you created earlier.

As for the link stuff, [this might help](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/JavaScript-not-working-on-Black-Berry-Simulator-8330/m-p/412687#M3397)